# How to forward broadcast Intent from BroadcastReceiver to app's activity (Convert broadcast intent to explicit intent)

Tags: android, android-intent, broadcastreceiver, android-broadcast, explicit-intent

I want to catch a broadcast intent, then forward the details of the intent to a specific Activity in my app.

So in my manifest file, I have this:

```
<receiver android:name="uk.floriansystems.carplayer.MediaButtonReceiver">
    <intent-filter android:priority="999">
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MEDIA_BUTTON"></action>
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

The BroadcastReceiver is this:

```
public class MediaButtonReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        KeyEvent keyEvent = (KeyEvent) intent.getParcelableExtra(Intent.EXTRA_KEY_EVENT);
        int keyEventKeyCode = keyEvent.getKeyCode();
        int keyEventAction = keyEvent.getAction();

        // I want to pass the above integers to my Activity, within the Intent
        // created below, in a tidy way:

        context.startActivity(new Intent(context, MainActivity.class).addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK));
    }
}
```

I want the activity to receive the keyEvent's action and keyCode via the intent that explicitly invokes the activity.

Is there a way I can re-use or clone the original broadcast intent, **modifying it as minimally as possible before sending it to the Activity?** Or are there similar alternatives for tidy/good practice ways of relaying the information to the Activity?

What I really want to do is maximise flexibility, so for example, it would (IMO) not be good if either:

1. the Intent I create for calling the Activity is only compatible with the Activity
2. The code in the Activity that handles the intent is only compatible with the intent created by my BroadcastReceiver

Should I just copy the action, category, data and extras from the first intent to the second? Are there any others bits I could/should copy?

Comment: see Intent ctors and/or Intent.fillin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using the copy constructor:

```
Intent activityIntent = new Intent(intent);
activityIntent.setClass(context, MainActivity.class);
context.startActivity(activityIntent);
```